# Excel or Google sheet cell value create in a different cell

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a requirement in Excel / Google sheet where-in if I enter a text in `A1` for the first time then the value should be auto-populated in `B1` and if I edit `A1` then the updated value should be auto-populated in `B2` and the next update of `A1` should be auto-populated in `B3`, so on.. without erasing the already created `B` column values.

Actually looking to set-up DB for `APPSHEET`.

Comment: Please provide samples of functions or other action you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

**For Excel**

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, N As Long, B1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    
    If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If B1.Value = "" Then
            B1.Value = A1.Value
        Else
            N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(N, "B").Value = A1.Value
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code supports keeping a historical record to changes made to cell **A1**.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

I just tried below and also seems to be working:

```js
    function onEdit(evt){
      
    var a1Value = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('forum').getRange('A1').getValue();
    
      for(var i =1;i<11;i++){
        var b1Obj = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('forum').getRange('B'+i);    
        if(b1Obj.getValue() == ''){
          b1Obj.setValue(a1Value);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('forum').getRange('A1').setValue('');
          break;
        }
      }
    
    }
```